# What does the phrase "要衝一波囉" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase

(Alternatively: 當然要衝一波囉)
It shows up a lot on the web but I can't find the meaning of it anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: google and baidu both turned up 0 results when i searched for this phrase in quotes

Comment: @小奥利奥 google turned up results for me: https://www.google.com.tw/search?source=hp&ei=qWVpX6yTE4Tz-gSwlpOgAg&q=%22%E8%A6%81%E8%A1%9D%E4%B8%80%E6%B3%A2%E5%9B%89%22&oq=%22%E8%A6%81%E8%A1%9D%E4%B8%80%E6%B3%A2%E5%9B%89%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1DRA1jwCmDtDGgAcAB4AIABAIgBAJIBAJgBAKABAaABAqoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjsi-vb3_vrAhWEuZ4KHTDLBCQQ4dUDCAY&uact=5

Comment: odd, now it wants to work....

Comment: ok, so I didnt recognize some of those traditional characters. now that I've done a bit of research I think it is saying "of course this will cause a wave" where a wave refers to a commotion or big news

Comment: any context?  Is it from a game or something?

Comment: Equivalent to "Let's go for broke"

Answer (score 1):

衝一波=rush forward
So 要衝一波囉 means "let's do this!"

Answer (score 0):

波 means 水波(sea wave), 一波 means 一次, 衝 is used for soldiers rushing to the enemy. The troops front is like a sea wave.

衝一波 means 'do something'

Answer (score 0):

衝一波 means you are eager/willing/excited/ready to do something. It's informal and colloquial.

e.g.

```
Q: 下個月在台北有五月天巡迴演唱會最後一場，去不去？
A: 那肯定要衝一波啊！

Q: 明天要不要跟隔壁班同學衝一波吃到飽？
A: 衝啊！
```